# Rails 4 Nested form not generating multiple

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am really new to nested forms in Rails, so I am sure I probably left something out here. I am following a Paperclip tutorial where an `article` has many `assets` (paperclip attachments)

The part I am stuck at is creating multiple file upload fields with the `article` controller.

You will see in the form partial that I have added the asset model near the bottom:

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :asset do |asset| %>
    <%= asset.file_field :image %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And in the article controller, I added what I thought would build that portion of the form 5 times:

```
  def new
    @article = Article.new
    5.times {@article.assets.build}
  end
```

For good measure, here is the article and asset models:

**article**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assets
end
```

**assets**

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article

    has_attached_file :image, 
        :style => {
            :thumb => '150x150#',
            :medium => '300x300>',
            :large => '600x600>'
        } 
end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get multiple fields for `:assets` generated, you need to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets` in your `Article` model.

```
# article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assets
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= f.fields_for :assets do |asset| %>
  <%= asset.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the nested fields as plural (same as the association):

```
<%= f.fields_for :assets do |asset| %>
  <%= asset.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just tried it - does not seem to fix the issue. Though it did not break the form either - It still outputs exactly one file field.